# Open youtube app from android webview

Tags: android

I have an android app and hosting a web site under webview, i have a requirement to open youtube app from within the html of webview. I am trying with normal anchor link and it is opening up within my app not outside of it.
Please let us know if there is a way to open it outside my app, not by using intent.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

1.
If you own the webpage and links, you can simply add target parameter to the  links like

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/video_id" **target="_blank"**>Open YouTube in new window</a>
```

2. You can also override this method to intercept links in we view

   ```
   myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
   @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  if(url.startsWith("www.youtube.Com") { 
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
     return true;}view.loadUrl(url); return false; } });
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but the link is opening within my android app. I want to get it open outside my app and i dont have access to android native code. I only have access to html. Pls help. Thanks!