# Open external app from Android WebView's URL

Tags: android, webview

On my Android App, I use a WebView to present the purchase flow. In the last step, the payment method is asked and a couple of options will trigger the start of a new App if installed. The most prominent example in our use case is MobilePay.

When the flow is on a classic browser, like Chrome, that page actually opens the Payment provider app. When I do it through a WebView, that doesn't happen.

I understand that this question is similar to many others, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869429/webview-open-links-in-external-apps-and-browsers-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469396/open-youtube-app-from-android-webview), but their solution is to intercept that link, and open it in Chrome or a standard browser. This is not applicable in my case, because I need to be able to return to the app when the Payment Provider's App has completed it's course, in order to have a confirmation screen.

**How can I let the browser have the same behavior as chrome in a WebView, and let it open an app if needed?**

I tried already many webview settings such as:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

And I also already override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in this way:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
    return handleUrl(view, url);
}

private boolean handleUrl(WebView view, String url) {
    /*I do some things here, but basically: */
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

Override [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and manually test if the URL uses your URI scheme, launching your app and returning true if it matches, otherwise returning false.

Comment: I already do override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, I'll update the question, but the URL does not use my URI scheme: the URL that opens the external app is from a different provider, not my app